# Cypress - stubbing using route(options) isn't work

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cypress

I try to simulate bad request by returning status code = 400.

I followed the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Options) and found that I need to use the route function with an options:

```js
cy.route({method : 'GET',url: 'users',status: 400});
cy.route({method : 'GET',url: '**/users/*',status: 400});
```

Both of those didn't work - running the Cypress Test Runner - the request isn't captured and the request is against the real server.
Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: The docs say "Please be aware that Cypress only currently supports intercepting XMLHttpRequests. Requests using the Fetch API and other types of network requests like page loads and <script> tags will not be intercepted or visible in the Command Log. See #95 for more details and temporary workarounds."

Are you using an unsupported type of network request?

Comment: 1. The interception is working using the syntax cy.route(url, response). It not working when calling the cy.route(options) overload.

2. The tested web app is an Angular app. The AJAX request type is XHR.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone will come across this issue, you need to pass response as one of the parameters, like this:

```
cy.route({
  method : 'GET',
  url: 'users',
  status: 400,
  response: {}
});
```